# Loading my existing file on Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, frameworks

Each time I run `php artisan serve` on my PHP Storm, I keep on getting this error.

```
Warning: Unknown: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0

Fatal error: Unknown: Failed opening required 'C:\xampp\htdocs\myWebsite/server.php' 
(include_path='.;C:\php\pear') in Unknown on line 0
```

Comment: Is your working directory has the `server.php` file ?

Comment: No, it doesn't. I don't know what could be the source of the error. Please help

Comment: You've missed this file : https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/server.php

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: I got the answer to my question. I am grateful to all the contributors. I sincerely want to apologize for the use of ''ASAP", I promised it will not happen again. Once again, Much regards to the entire community.